# Displaying field value in SSRS Report Header with custom code

Tags: reporting-services, header

I tried to implement this code to display data in the header:

[MSDN - displaying-information-from-datasets-in-the-header-report-builder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ca6dbd94-8500-4f09-ade1-44bccf08b6ed/displaying-information-from-datasets-in-the-header-report-builder-30-ssrs-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices)

I have created custom code:

```
Public Shared Data1 As Object = ""

Public Function SetData(NewValue As Object, Field As String)

  If Field = “SoldInvestorName” Then

   If NewValue > "" Then

     Data1 = NewValue

   End If

  End If

End Function



Public Function GetData(Field As String)

  If Field = “SoldInvestorName” Then

   Return CStr(Data1)

  End If

End Function
```

But could not figure out where to put a new text box in the report body since I have multiple groups. I tried all groups, but in any case the last page of top (first) group displays wrong Page Header value from the subsequent group.

The report looks like this:

> **Page Header**
>
> Details: has field SoldInvestorName which I need to display in Page Header
>
> **Group3** Footer: CategoryCode
>
> **Group2** Footer: InvestorCode
>
> **Group1** Footer: LoanServicingSoldId

New text box expression I have is this:
Code.SetData(First(Fields!SoldInvestorName.Value,**"LoanServicingSoldId"**),"SoldInvestorName")

And Page header expression:
Code.GetData("SoldInvestorName")

Group1 has a page break for new group. So last page for Group1 always has incorrect value in the page header from the subsequent Group1.

Here is the design
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKqpD.jpg

Comment: Show your current report design, what it renders now and what you want to achieve, add sample data if relevant.

Comment: I don't know how to add screenshots here.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation in StackOverflow to insert them directly but you could save the images to some online service like imgur and then edit your question with a link to the  image

Comment: Here is the design screenshot. ![Report Design] (https://imgur.com/a/Bb4aMTE)